# Sum and Inner Join with Group by in Sql Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Please help me to get a expected output.
 I have 2 tables

1.LeaveEntries

```
     emp_id   LeaveTypeSName      LeaveStatus      FromDate         ToDate
     ----------------------------------------------------------------------
       1            CL             Full Day      21/07/2014       21/07/2014
       1            SL             Half Day      21/07/2014       21/07/2014
       1            CL             Full Day      21/07/2014       21/07/2014
       1            SL             Full Day      21/07/2014       21/07/2014
       1            CL             Half Day      21/07/2014       21/07/2014
       1            CL             Full Day      21/07/2014       24/07/2014
```

2.EmployeeLeaves2014

```
      emp_id   leaveTypesName      allowedLeaves
     -------------------------------------------
         1          CL                  12
         1          SL                  6
         1          FH                  5
         1          EL                  12
         1          PL                  6
```

And this is my Query

```
SELECT 
    c.LeaveTypeSName
    ,a.AllowedLeaves
    ,SUM(case when LeaveStatus='FullDay' then DATEDIFF(day, FromDate, ToDate)+1 else 0.5 end) AS 'leavetaken' 
FROM EmployeeLeaves2014 a
    INNER JOIN LeaveEntries b ON a.Emp_Id = b.Emp_Id
WHERE b.emp_id = '1'
GROUP BY LeaveTypeSName,AllowedLeaves
```

Expected Output:

```
     LeaveTypeSName  allowedLeaves      leaveTaken
     -------------------------------------------
         CL             12                  6.5
         SL             6                   1.5
         FH             5                   0
         EL             12                  0
         PL             6                   0
```

Comment: @kristianp, this is a perfectly acceptable question. OP has shown work and expected input and output.  What else would you have him add?

Comment: Exactly correct @paqogomez +1. I think the comment owner didn't see the entire question properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try:

```
select 
    emp_id,
    leaveTypesName,
    allowedLeaves,
    ISNULL((select SUM(datediff(d, FromDate, ToDate)+
                (case when LeaveStatus='Half Day' then .5 else 1 end)) 
    from LeaveEntries b where b.emp_id=a.emp_id and b.LeaveTypeSName=a.leaveTypesName), 0) as LeavesTaken
from EmployeeLeaves2014 a
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8151ea/1)

Comment: Probably on the right track here.. but you have a syntax error. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/39b01/7

Comment: I think it's the issue related to insert... Please check the edited fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8151ea/1

Comment: i want to subtract allowedleaves and leavestaken column how can i??

Comment: I tried with       ISNULL(AllowedLeaves, 0) - ISNULL(LeavesTaken, 0) but its showing erroe Invalid column name 'LeavesTaken'.

Comment: @DileepKumar You need it as an extra column or in place of LeavesTaken?

Comment: I got the Output Thank you TechDo

Answer (score 1):

Another approach using windowing functions:

```
select distinct 
b.leavetypesname, 
b.allowedleaves,
coalesce
(sum(datediff(day,fromdate,todate) 
 + case 
       when leavestatus = 'Full Day' then 1 
       else 0.5 
 end) over (partition by a.leavetypesname order by a.emp_id)
 ,0) as leaveTaken

from leaveentries a
right join employeeleaves2014 b 
on a.emp_id = b.emp_id 
and a.leavetypesname = b.leavetypesname
order by leaveTaken desc
```

[Demo](http://rextester.com/IHSK79788)